# bash cd too many arguments error on raspberry

Tags: bash, arguments, cd

I'm getting a `bash : cd : too many arguments` error for this bit of code.

```
cd ~/Freenove_Three-wheeled_Smart_Car_Kit_for_Raspberry_Pi/mjpg-streamer make USE_LIBV4L2=true clean all
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cd` command (change directory) takes only one argument. If I had to guess, I'd say that you've combined multiple lines into one. Perhaps it should be:

`cd ~/Freenove_Three-wheeled_Smart_Car_Kit_for_Raspberry_Pi/mjpg-streamer; make USE_LIBV4L2=true clean all`

The semi-colon separates multiple commands.

Comment: I think that did it thanks I just couldn't see it and im only on day 2 lol

Comment: @TrevorHead Here at Stack Overflow, if an answer helped you, instead of commenting "Thanks!", please mark it as accepted. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066444/2745495), you can also use `&&` to connect the 2 commands.

```
cd some_directory && make USE_LIBV4L2=true clean all
```

The difference is that `&&` is like an AND operator, it will only execute the next command if the previous command did not result in an error. This means, it will only execute `make` if `cd` to `some_directory` was successful. The `;` will execute commands sequentially, whether or not the previous command was successful.